# ERROR: already an object named 'TableName' in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am getting error message saying object named "Bank_Test" already exists in the database. I used the `Drop table` and `Drop procedure` functions but it is still giving me the same error message. I tried changing the name but it still gives same error message. Please help!

```sql
USE [Test_1]
GO
Create Procedure [dbo].[Bank_Test]
AS
SELECT DISTINCT a.PatientAccountID 'AccountId'
        ,a.PatientLocationName 'Location’
        ,b.OrderAbbreviation 'OrderAbbreviation'
        ,b.OrderId 'OrderId'
        ,b.CreationTime 'CreationTime'

INTO Test_1.dbo.Bank_Test 

FROM dbo.PatientVisit a with (nolock)
INNER JOIN dbo.Order b with (nolock)
ON a.PatientVisit_oid=b.PatientVisit_oid
WHERE a.VisitTypeCode= 'IP'
AND a.LastName != 'Testdummy'
ORDER BY a.PatientAccountID
```

Error message:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3, Procedure BloodTest, Line 3
> There is
>   already an object named 'BloodTest' in the database.

Comment: Right click on stored procedure directory and click refresh. If that doesn't help let me know

Comment: Try changing the name of the procedure to something else... looks like Stored Proc and Table name are the same, not sure if that would be an issue.

Comment: Also your create procedure declares Bank_Test...your error states BloodTest???

Comment: I did refresh the stored procedure directory after drop function it won't show the procedure and when I try with differnt name it gives me an error message. Also for some reason it is creating Store Procedure instead of table.

Comment: @AlicaShah To create the table you must execute the stored procedure in your query window `EXEC dbo.Bank_Test` ...After you create the procedure go back in the stored procedure and change `CREATE` to `ALTER` then hit `execute query` if it says "query executed successfully" then the stored procedure is in the data base.  Execute the query as stated above and should work.

Comment: Does it show up in the list of procedures under Programmability? Maybe you can delete it from there.

Comment: Are you getting the error trying to run the create procedure script or running the stored proc?

Comment: Also, why is your stored proc creating a table with the same name as the proc you are making?  That will cause a name conflict.

Comment: I am getting this error when I use the Command :Execute dbo.Blood_test

Comment: when I use the query above and try changing different name it says Command(s) completed successfully. and when I execute the procedure it give me the error.

Comment: @AlicaShah don't use `EXECUTE` proper syntax is `EXEC`

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that your stored proc is trying to create a table when you run it named Bank_Test.  Since you already have a proc named Bank_Test it fails with the error you provided.

Just a guess, but I am betting you want to insert records into a table, not SELECT ... INTO.  "Select into" creates a new table every time, which is probably not what you want.  You probably want to add records to an existing table, something like this

```
INSERT INTO your_table (columns)
SELECT things_go_here
```

Comment: This is probably the answer

Comment: Every time he runs that proc he makes a new table.  It will only ever (at most) once without an error.

Comment: Right...because the table was already created with `SELECT INTO`....must change to `INSERT INTO`

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping that item first: [Drop Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174969.aspx)

The last time you ran the procedure, the object was created, then the procedure failed.

```sql
USE [Test_1]
GO
Drop Procedure [dbo].[Bank_Test] -- call this first
Create Procedure [dbo].[Bank_Test]
AS
SELECT DISTINCT a.PatientAccountID 'AccountId'
        ,a.PatientLocationName 'Location’
        ,b.OrderAbbreviation 'OrderAbbreviation'
        ,b.OrderId 'OrderId'
        ,b.CreationTime 'CreationTime'

INTO Test_1.dbo.Bank_Test 

FROM dbo.PatientVisit a with (nolock)
INNER JOIN dbo.Order b with (nolock)
ON a.PatientVisit_oid=b.PatientVisit_oid
WHERE a.VisitTypeCode= 'IP'
AND a.LastName != 'Testdummy'
ORDER BY a.PatientAccountID
```

Most likely, that procedure still exists (at least until the garbage collector takes it).

Comment: The SO user is not executing the stored procedure `EXEC dbo.Bank_Test` is needed

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote, Jeff. Are you thinking his Error Message does **not** come when he attempts to execute the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement?

Comment: Thats the way I took it. By what the SO user was stating I took it as the SO user thinking the table was going to be created without executing the stored procedure.  I wrote another answer below just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Since your table is in the same database state this  `INTO Bank_Test` rather than this `INTO Test_1.dbo.Bank_Test`...I believe the DBMS thinks you are trying to insert into your stored procedure.  I only use dbo.whatever when references a table from another database.

Also, add a verb to your stored procedure because it is "doing something"

i.e. `CreateBankTest`